# Combining two plot types in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I want to combine xyline plot with bar plot in excel. I created xyline plot and then added new series with a hope that I can chance the series 1 later.

Step 1: But it turned to be not true, see the results. Particularly misalignment of the axis.  created xy line plot:

[image]

Step 2: Added line series 2, then changed back the series 1 to bar.

[image]

But it turned to be bad:

[image]

Any resolution? I need to do this excel, I am using 2007 version. Scripts to fix such problem are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A column chart has a Category X axis, not a value X axis. If you want the columns placed according to their numeric value, then you can use Error Bars.

Create error bars with the "Minus" option, no caps and 100% error. Then format the line color and thickness. (see screenshot). Then remove the actual series line (I've left it faintly visible in the screenshot)

[image]

Comment: thanks, What do you mean by XY chart ? XY (Scatter , or line) ? I really want series 1 to be bar - thus line plot overlayed over bar, but the matter is fit of the plot.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I've edited the answer.

Comment: You really shouldn't use a smoothed line. In this case particularly, your data points represent binned counts (whole numbers), so it would be useful to use markers as well as straight lines. otherwise, it gives the impression that you have a smooth albeit wavy distribution. Also smoothed lines make it look like the red distribution dips below zero, which is silly.